# How can i redirect to template in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have the symfony controller where i am saving `entity`.

I want to redirect to `template` after saving entity. I don't have `route` for that defined.

Is there any way to dynamically define route and redirect based on template

like:

```
        return $this->redirect('DefaultBundle:Default:success.html.twig');
```

I have many templates with simple message like error , success etc.

I don't want to make controllers for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirectiong for template is impossible (and illogical). You have to redirect for route, but defining controller is not necessary.

```
success_template:
    path: /success
    defaults:
        _controller:  FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:     'DefaultBundle:Default:success.html.twig'
```

And in your controller:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success_template'));`
```

[Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->render('YourBundle:folder:file.html.twig');
```

if the page you want to render is directly under /views:

```
return $this->render('YourBundle::file.html.twig');
```